# Disagreement with downvotes & on hold on specific question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, closed-questions

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204669/how-to-get-all-week-end-dates-of-the-month-for-all-12-months) out.

This question has at least 4 downvotes (I voted up), and at least 5 "unclear" votes which lead to it being on hold.

My disagreement with these is very strong, and here's why:

1. I suspect many of the downvotes/close votes were placed because of the inclusion of an image. We don't like images because we can't copy-paste stuff off them - but this isn't needed in this case. To be fair, the subject of the post covers its specification in its entirety, and the image is just an assistance.
2. I truly doubt the request is unclear. I think it is CRYSTAL clear, and that has lead to it already having two answers, both of which I think are correct. One is mine, and the other one comes from one of the persons that *voted to close the subject for being unclear*.

I would like your opinion on that matter. The only thing I could think this new user has done wrongly is maybe not research enough - [but I can find 100 posts <del>*of today*</del> which required *less* research than this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/924369/top-questions-by-effort), and had no downvotes or closevotes.

I'd like to hear opinions on these, which may further my understanding of the way things work here.

Comment: Given that there are two answer that assume different things about what op wants, unclear seems to be a good fit. You assume that op wants to have 7 day steps starting from a given date. Someone else assumes they are looking for sundays. It could also be that they have a table to dates and want to have them grouped by month or ordered by date. They could also be asking how to get the yellow background for the header.

Comment: _I suspect many of the downvotes/close votes were placed because of the inclusion of an image._ Why would you suspect that? Quoting the tooltip, downvotes are to be used when _This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_. That applies perfectly here, so why are you looking for other reasons for the downvotes?

Comment: That question, with or without the image, is not in a good state.

Comment: Far more concerning are the (currently) 2 sympathy upvotes that question has received. There's no version of reality where that post meets the quality guidelines to even exist here, let alone be rated as good. Some people are really ruining the system.

Comment: @BDL The assumption is the same: "Return all Sunday dates in 2018". I just made a "lazy" answer, while Salmans's one could work for other years too. I find it highly unprobable the OP needs a group-by judging by the subject (or maybe this is their end purpose, but they are not burdening us with that, thus providing a minimal example, right?). And I also think the header thing is highly improbable, since any ssms user quite quickly notices that sub-headers are an impossibility on queries.

Comment: @Clive Which of the three parts "apply perfectly here"? I suppose the "no research effort" part? I know this subject pretty well, it's one of the first things I could *not* do when learning the language. Notice how while the request "feels easy", both the answers include recursion, which is not a beginner concept in tsql.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis All 3 for me

Comment: Why "sympathy"? Despite the odds (it seems by end of the day *my* question wil have -1000), I still think it's a good question. Sympathy would be if one who did not believe this, upvoted because they felt "sad".

Comment: @George, votes in meta are used to signal agreement/disagreement, apart from the usual. They are used much more freely than in main.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis It is empirically, demonstrably, a terrible question. So I don't believe that you or anyone else has voted on it with anything other than sympathy for the OP in mind.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis this has been trend (that I've noticed) since the "welcoming". Posts which clearly show no effort / research or even any attempts get up-voted just so people feel "welcomed". This question and the voting on it is case in point.

Comment: I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53204669/2) was the version that was up when this question got its answers and got closed, which is arguably even worse. It's weird that the suggested edit includes information about what's considered a weekend for the OP...

Comment: The only domain where things are demonstrably correct is science. You are in effect saying "shame on me" for having a different opinion? I did not upvote the post because I felt sad about the person - I believe it is a good post. If 99% disagree with me, fine, this is what votes are for, so we may deduce a result - but it doesn't mean the ones with the fewer votes should be *ashamed* they did this. If my question had +6 instead of -6, and your answer had -7 instead of +7, would that give me the right to tell "shame on you"?

Comment: That the same user answered the question an VTCd it as "unclear" is silly, to say the least.

Comment: @yivi I voted to close before looking at the screenshot. I am not much into discussing these issues on meta but here is what I have to say: I saw a question that could be answered and I answered.

Comment: @Salman then you could have redacted your vote, once you saw the screenshot and realized it was indeed answerable. It is a bit absurd that you voted to close as unclear and answered, which means it's somewhat clear for you....

Comment: @Patrice just an *FYI*, I think the word you are looking for is ['*retracted*'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=retracted&oq=retracted&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3463j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)' and not ['*redacted*'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=redacted&oq=redacted+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1392j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: It's not ok to pursue to users who posted the questions/answers being discussed in this post onto other posts to downvote them. This type of targeted behaviour is not accepted on the site.

Comment: @Script47 indeed, this is one of the words where the fact I'm French screws me over ("redacted" in french can be "retire", and my lack of coffee this morning made me confuse both). Thanks for the correction!

Comment: "I know this subject pretty well, it's one of the first things I could not do when learning the language." Nothing wrong with that at all; that's literally the reason SO exists.  The point being made is that not knowing how to do something means research; showing effort to solve your problem prior to asking.  I can't see the question, but I suspect that end of things wasn't done.  It's not about difficulty; it's about personal investment.

Comment: Bad arguments or no arguments at all just downvoting, provoking and closing down the post instead of removing comments is what I experienced

Comment: I refined the post, put a lot job, got called ego, called for input and got screwed. I said difference in color of my design proposal makes difference. That needed a proof, so I gave analogy with traffic light. They tried to have me want site to be a traffic light. I asked to talk with a designer or programmer. Post closed. Resaon: I didnt ask for input. What?

Comment: A well formed post should not be closed because of provocations against the poster. In first place all comments should be deleted,

Answer (score 16):

> I suspect many of the downvotes/close votes were placed because of the inclusion of an image.

You could be right, there's no realistic way to tell, but it's much more likely that the downvotes were for the proper reason, which is taken from the tooltip on the downvote arrow:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

The question clearly shows no research effort, so downvoting is the sanctioned action to take.

> I truly doubt the request is unclear.

Fair enough, but I personally think it *isn't* clear enough to pass muster with our quality standards. So the closure works for me too.

> but I can find 10 posts of today , which required less research than this one, and had no downvotes or closevotes.

There's no real point comparing posts in this manner. Maybe this post had more views, maybe it had more views by people with enough reputation to vote, maybe something else. You can't use the existence, or voting on, of one post to justify the content of another post. Always apply the guidelines and quality standards to a post in isolation.

Comment: This, very much this: *Always apply the guidelines and quality standards to a post in isolation.*